# Call to undefined method DB::prepare()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO statement to fetch details from DB, Below is the `pdo` that i am using

```
 <?php
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_NAME', 's_ao');
    define('DB_USER', 'sd');
    define('DB_PASS', '****');
    define('DB_CHAR', 'utf8');

    class DB
    {
    protected static $instance = null;

    final private function __construct() {}
    final private function __clone() {}

    public static function instance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null)
        {
            $opt  = array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => TRUE,
                PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS    => array('myPDOStatement'),
            );
            $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset='.DB_CHAR;
            self::$instance = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
    public static function __callStatic($method, $args) {
        return call_user_func_array(array(self::instance(), $method), $args);
    }
    }

    class myPDOStatement extends PDOStatement
    {
    function execute($data = array())
    {
        parent::execute($data);
        return $this;
    }
    }
```

Now when i use

```
    $sid = $_GET['pmdfe23'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM checks WHERE id = '".$sid."'"; 
    //echo $sql;
    $data = DB::prepare($sql)->execute()->fetchAll();
```

I am getting error as `Call to undefined method DB::prepare()`. Please help this to sort this out as it is was working locally without any problems and when i uploaded to live server then i am getting these errors.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? `__callStatic` was added in 5.3.0.

Comment: on server.. PHP version is 5 .. any way out?

Comment: Upgrade to something that isn't prehistoric. 5.3.0 came out 5 years ago.

Comment: it is 5.2.17 as version on server

Comment: OK, that's not actually prehistoric, since it came out 18 months after 5.3.0. But if you want to use this feature, you need to use a version of PHP that has it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the purpose of the `__callStatic` wrapper? You already have a factory setup to return a database object which already provides you the concrete methods, resulting in calls like this:

```
$data = DB::instance()->prepare($sql)->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Comment: He's trying to avoid having to write `DB::instance()` all the time, by automatically forwarding methods to the instance.

Comment: `DB::instance` worked for me .. not sure why? now if i try to execute `$data = DB::instance()->prepare($sql)->execute([$id])->fetchAll();` then i get error like `syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'`

Comment: @CodeFreak , `[]` array syntax started from 5.4

Comment: means i can not use `?` in queries if i want to use

Comment: @CodeFreak If you use an old version, you'd better get in the habit of checking the documentation for when features were added.

Comment: @CodeFreak You have to write `array($id)` instead of `[$id]`.

Comment: @Barmar: Right, but at what cost? Making two extra calls just to lighten the footprint seems like a waste to me.

Comment: It's called abstraction.

Comment: @Barmar: I know what abstraction is, my point is that it's useless in this case.